# Excel VBA - Check cells in a column do not contain the string 8254 and display MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to put some vba code together to check if the contents in every cell from L2 down to the last row of data (until a blank cell is found) does not contain the string '8254' The number codes in column L are 27 characters long and always contain '8254' as the last 4 digits. So if I can verify '8254' in every cell then the format/code is correct (some number codes are incorrect and need to be investigated). If the string '8254' is not present in one or more of the cells, display a MsgBox warning there are error(s) in the column.

I have been trying to make the below code work, however I am new to vba and need some help

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

```
Sub CheckCodes()

'Check column 'L' for Non Standard Number Codes
Dim code As Range

 For Each code In Range("L2", Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If VBA.Right$(VBA.Trim$(code), 4) <> "8254" Then
        MsgBox "Non Standard Number Codes Found!  " & vbNewLine & "Check Number Codes  ", , "ADVISORY!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next code
End Sub
```

Comment: If `8254` is expected as the last four digits of the 27 digit number can you not simply use: `If VBA.Right$(cells(i, 1), 4) <> "8254" Then MsgBox "Non standard...."`?

Comment: @alexp Thanks Alex - I tried this however I could not get it to work. I am new to vba though so not 100% sure how to construct things so it might just be me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue was that the code was checking a number of blank cells down to line L1000 and causing the issue. I modified as per below so it only checks to the bottom of the data and it is working fine. Thanks for all your kind help and comments.

```
Sub CheckCodes()

'Check column 'L' for Non Standard Number Codes
Dim code As Range

 For Each code In Range("L2", Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If VBA.Right$(VBA.Trim$(code), 4) <> "8254" Then
        MsgBox "Non Standard Number Codes Found!  " & vbNewLine & "Check Number Codes  ", , "ADVISORY!"
    Exit Sub
End If
Next code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `right` function (assumes check is that `8234` are always last four digits):

```
Sub CheckCodes()
    Dim code As Range

    For Each code In Range("L2:L1000")
        If VBA.Right$(VBA.Trim$(code), 4) <> "8234" Then
            MsgBox "Non Standard Number Codes Found!  " & vbNewLine & "Check Number Codes  ", , "ADVISORY!"
            Exit Sub
        End If            
    Next code
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. This works but displays a msgbox when "8254" is present. I need it the other way around so if "8254" is not in the cell then it displays the msgbox. I tried using   "If VBA.Right$(code, 4) <> "8234" Then" however it does not work - Thanks

Comment: How are your numbers formatted? As values, text? Can you show a sample?

Comment: Yes sure please see a couple of examples. BTP000001861531280005018254
BWE000001867631022959008254
The first 3 characters are always text followed by all numbers with the last 4 always being "8254". So the best way of picking up errors is to check that "8254" is appearing as the last 4 digits. If not then display a msgbox error - Thanks

Comment: I tested it and works for me. Given that you are getting false positives (i.e. saying not equal to `8254` when `8254` appears to the last 4 digits) it could be that you have trailing white spaces? Try my updated code that works around that with the `Trim$`.method.